# How can I register on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, openid, sign-up

How can I register on this website?

When I click "register", it asks me for my OpenID.
So I gave my Yahoo ID, but nothing happened.

Can anyone of you please guide me on this?

Comment: It looks like you are already registered :) ... Welcome to Stack Overflow! ... Here's your public profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/259939/anu

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: SO registration is so smooth and seamless you don't even notice you have been signed up.

Answer (score 2):

OpenID was depreciated at some point, and the existing answers are no longer valid.

You need to click on the Sign Up option on the top right of the page

[image]

For Public Q&A, you have three options at the moment

[image]

You can use a google or facebook login, or a create a SE login with a displayname email and password.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the "register" link at the top of the page
2. Click the OpenID provider of your choice
3. Confirm
4. Done

Comment: Er, *what* "register" link? It's just "login", right? Oh, I guess I get it: one will probably see "register" *after* using an OpenID to log in first. So then Step 0 is: log in? (Screen capture for very first usage at http://img.skitch.com/20100211-k7x9ye71iihqkkt8eys2c8gnec.png -- assuming Private Browsing does not send you any cookies that might reveal you already know me.)

Comment: register appears for unregistered users, which this user is

Answer (score 0):

OpenID is a system where you only need to enter information such as your name and location once. When logging in to site which uses OpenID such as SO it requests a permission to use the credentials from the OpenID provider you entered.

This means that when you log in to your Yahoo ID, the site calls the Yahoo ID provider for your credentials which you either allow or deny (*some providers use the word "share" for this*) - and apparently you did allow - and then starts treating you as a logged in user without the need to create a yet another account for some site on the Internet.